# How to make a Google map drawable of overlay movable/dragging it in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application, a marker is positioned on a default position.
Now what I want is that user can drag the marker to any other location.
How to do this?

I can create marker on other location `onTap` event, but I want to drag the marker.

Is it possible in Android?

Answer (score 0):

chckout following project.Hope its useful.

http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/